# D3D11 - How to enable HDR on display without Windows 10

Tags: directx-11

I'm trying to use HDR rendering on a video player that I'm working on and I can't seem to activate HDR on my display (yes, my display supports HDR), on all the code samples that I've seen, everything is pointing to setting the Color Format to R10G10B10A2_UNorm (I'm using SharpDX) and referenced all the articles in this article https://www.asawicki.info/news_1703_programming_hdr_monitor_support_in_direct3d, but I still can't enable HDR on my display.

As an example, if you know madVR can actually do this (it can force you're display to enable HDR without going through Windows 10). I think this is called HDR passthrough. How is this done?

Here's the code that I have that's working and it can actually draw a white screen.

```
this.d3dDevice = new D3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, new[] { FeatureLevel.Level_11_1, FeatureLevel.Level_11_0, });

SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription1 swapChainDescription_ = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription1()
{
    AlphaMode = SharpDX.DXGI.AlphaMode.Ignore,
    Width = Proc2.Width,
    Height = Proc2.Height,
    Format = Format.R10G10B10A2_UNorm,
    Scaling = SharpDX.DXGI.Scaling.None,
    BufferCount = 3,
    SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.FlipDiscard,
    Flags = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch,
    Usage = SharpDX.DXGI.Usage.BackBuffer | SharpDX.DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription() { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
    Stereo = false,
};

parentSwapchain = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain1(factory2, d3dDevice, this.renderForm.Handle, ref swapChainDescription_, new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainFullScreenDescription()
{
    RefreshRate = new Rational(144, 1),
    Scaling = SharpDX.DXGI.DisplayModeScaling.Unspecified,
    Windowed = true,
    ScanlineOrdering = SharpDX.DXGI.DisplayModeScanlineOrder.Unspecified,
}
);
```

Can anyone point me out to which part I'm missing? I just want to force my display to enable HDR using my Direct3D code.

Answer (score 0):

Digging more into this... I found that Kodi has an HDR version that can actually do this: https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=349861. It looks like there's a Windows API (starting from 1903, I think) that enables you to do this via `DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo` and  `DisplayConfigSetDeviceInfo`. It's not straightforward though as you need to query the display's capabilities first and set it. I was able to write a test code in C++ to do this. I just need to do some pInvoke to get it to run on C#.